# Is there any tool to profile each layer of a DNN in Pytorch and Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch

I want to know the execution time of each layer of a DNN. 
Is there any tool can profile each layer?
I know I can insert some print in a model, but I am not sure it will be accurate.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: What do you mean by profile?

Comment: @AndréPacheco For example, another framework Caffe provide "caffe time" to measure the execution time of each layer. However, the tools provided by Pytorch and TF cannot provide the higher level information.

Comment: @LennoxWu Gotcha! The closest tool I know is the [torch summary](https://github.com/sksq96/pytorch-summary)

Comment: @AndréPacheco Thank you. It is useful to me.

Comment: @AndréPacheco Sure. I think the tool can satisfy my partial requirements. The tool cannot measure the execution time of each layer, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the size and parameters of each layer you can use the [torch summary](https://github.com/sksq96/pytorch-summary).

To compute time the execution time of each layer, you can use the [torchprof](https://github.com/awwong1/torchprof).

I don't know any project that merges both libs. Maybe it's your opportunity (lol)

Comment: torchprof is deprecated now, and torch.profiler should be used